# What is the reason for qubit indexing in Stim's surface code skipping some indices?

Tags: stim, surface-code

A very silly question perhaps but why does Stim skip certain numbers when it initializes the surface code? For example, a distance 2 surface code has 4 data qubits and 3 ancilla qubits. The Stim rotated surface code indexes these 7 qubits with 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 12.

```
QUBIT_COORDS(1, 1) 1
QUBIT_COORDS(2, 0) 2
QUBIT_COORDS(3, 1) 3
QUBIT_COORDS(1, 3) 6
QUBIT_COORDS(2, 2) 7
QUBIT_COORDS(3, 3) 8
QUBIT_COORDS(2, 4) 12
```

Is there a reason for skipping certain indices in the assignment above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the generation code is computing the indices directly from the coordinates using some simple math that doesn't account for the jagged boundaries skipping qubits. It was just easier to write that way.

The holes in coordinate system are clearer at higher distances. Here's the output of

```python
stim.Circuit.generated(
    "surface_code:rotated_memory_z",
    rounds=3,
    distance=6,
).diagram('detslice-svg', tick=11)
```

with the coordinates of the missing qubits drawn in:

[image]

(In case you're confused that this looks like an unrotated surface code state, it's because we're peeking at the state in the middle of the circuit cycle instead of between the measure and reset layers.)

And here's the same thing at distance 2, along with the qubit indices and indicators showing the zig zag paths being used for the indexing:

[image]